# Please can you check my proof about this function?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I defined $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as 
$$ f(x) = x \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x) $$

Then I calim it is not differentiable except at $0$. Please can you check my proof?

If $c \neq 0$ there are two cases:

If $c \in \mathbb Q$ let $x_n \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ be a sequence $x_n \to c$. Then 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{f(x_n) - f(c) \over x_n - c}  = \infty$$
therefore the limit at $c$ does not exist.

If If $c \notin \mathbb Q$ let $x_n \in \mathbb Q$ be a sequence $x_n \to c$. Then 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{f(x_n) - f(c) \over x_n - c}  = \infty$$
therefore the limit at $c$ does also not exist.

Therefore for $c \neq 0$ the function $f$ is not differentiable at $c$. If $c=0$ then 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0}{f(x) - f(c) \over x - c}  = \lim_{x\to 0} \chi_{\mathbb Q}(x) = 1$$
therefore $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Your proof seems o.k; just  you need be careful about the sign of your limit it may be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$; depending on the sign of $c\in \mathbb R.$

Comment: In the $c=0$ case, while $x \to 0$ it takes on irrational values, and at those values the difference quotient is zero. So since each of $0,1$ is taken on infinitely often as $x \to 0$ by the difference quotient, $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: It seems to me that it's easier to prove a stronger result, namely that your function is not continuous at each nonzero value of $x.$ (Unless you don't have "finite derivative exists at a point implies continuity at the point" available to use.) It may help in visualizing what is happening (both for $x=0,$ where the function is **not** differentiable, and for nonzero values of $x$) by observing that the graph of your function consists of a set that is dense in the line $y=x$ union a set that is dense in the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I think if I replace $x$ with $x^2$ it will work.

Comment: Yes, $x^2$ works, or even $|x|^p$ for any fixed value of $p$ such that $p > 1.$ Similarly for $|x|^{p}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ (defined to be $0$ when $x=0$), where $p$ is a constant greater than $1.$